# How to apply specific patch to linux kernel 6.2.1-060201-generic x86_64

Tags: drivers, kernel, hp, fan, overheating

I have looked/searched and found no real answers/guidance on the proper way to get this done. I am hoping to find someone who can help me with applying a specific kernel patch (commit - I think is the proper term) to my kernel for driver support so that I can have more control over my PC's hardware.

Right now, my thermals are not properly managed by the current kernel due to some unknown reason, and the temp thresholds at which my fans activate or increase RPM are way too high.  I need my fans to follow a better curve to prevent overheating.  This [site](https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-5.18-HP-Omen-Thermal) is exactly what I need for my exact model of computer.

Which now leads to [this](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/pdx86/platform-drivers-x86.git/commit/?h=for-next&id=286e937efbc7177c114e80aae9b402131e3886c1)

I would very much appreciate some guidance on how an inexperienced Linux user can apply the above patch to my current kernel.  `uname -srm` gives me `Linux 6.2.1-060201-generic x86_64`.

Please let me know if I can give you any more information.

The reason I need to do this is that this patch would allow me to better control thermals and fan speeds where tools like `pwmconfig`, `lm-sensors`, and `fancontrol` cannot.  `Psensor` output below:

[image: Psensor output on Ubuntu-based distribution]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this part of the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/applying-patches.html) help you?

Comment: @Rishon_JR I have tried to follow those exact directions, but have been unsuccessful in making that work for my purposes. If you look at the links I provided and follow it to the commit I mentioned, I think all I need to do is include the code into my current kernel.  At least that is my understanding.  ``patch -pl -i '/home/$USER/Downloads/platform-drivers-x86-286e937efbc7177c114e80aae9b402131e3886c1' 
patch: **** strip count l is not a number``  I don't know how to progress from here and why I get this specific error.

Comment: Is there a specific file I need to look for in the downloaded patch .tar?

Comment: Try this: `patch -p0 -i /home/$USER/Downloads/platform-drivers-x86-286e937efbc7177c114e80aae9b402131e3886c1`

Comment: If that doesn't work then try this: `patch -p1 -i /home/$USER/Downloads/platform-drivers-x86-286e937efbc7177c114e80aae9b402131e3886c1
`